# Does reading sentences one by one contributes to better comprehension of the text?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception, learning, reference-request, reading

Does reading sentences one by one beside a picture
(as shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BijgqxztEpg) video of [this](https://github.com/lucidl/tedegraph) project) contributes to better comprehension of the text,
due to better readability, focus and other factors? In opposite to classical reading?

I have already one feedback from person with dyslexia and she tells she reads fantastic with it.

Comment: Apprehension is worry or fear of something negative that will/may happen, like you might feel apprehensive telling your roommate that you've just eaten all of their favorite foods from the refrigerator. Do you mean comprehension?

Comment: This question might get a better answer, or an answer at all, at the linguistics.SE

Comment: @BryanKrause: apprehension also means ability to apprehend or understand; understanding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apprehension_(understanding). But I don't know whether OP means better understanding the text or better remembering the text or a mixture of both.

Comment: @QuoraFeans Apprehension in that context would not have fit the context here. Might have been where OP misremembered the word from, though.

Comment: @BryanKrause I found bad translation in the dictionary.